# Creating a coupled inductor with 2 discrete inductors?

Tags: inductor

I am working on a EL driver board using Maxim Integrated MAX14521 [1]. The application circuit of the evaluation board [2] uses GA3250 [3], which is designed specifically for the MAX14521. Now, this part is not available via Digikey. I can get them directly from the manufacturer, but I wonder if I can create an equivalent circuit using 2 inductors. I doubt I can, but I am asking here because I don't see why a chip would require a special discrete component!

[1] https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/power/MAX14521E.html

[2] https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX14521EEVKIT.pdf

[3] http://www.coilcraft.com/pdfs/ga3250.pdf

Comment: Doubtful you can make any meaningful coupling with loose COTS inductors. Order samples from Coilcraft you wind your own.

Comment: It may not look like it, but the input circuit of the MAX14521 as shown in the datasheet has a *transformer* on input. LX switches between open and ground (see internal circuit on page 9 of the datasheet), which creates an 1:8 autotransformation. See the specs of the transformer coil. So no, you cannot replace a transformer by two simple coils.

Comment: It is difficult to impossible to achieve a large ratio step-up with high-efficiency without using a transformer or a tapped inductor. The inductor and switch device capacitance limit the step-up that can practical.